# Developing iOS apps using adobe flash cs5?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, actionscript, air

I remember that I've heard about a flash cs5 feature which lets the developers export their project to iphone (.ipa file) and pretty much make games for the iphone using actionscript 3,

Is that really possible to do?

I've also heard that now in order to develop games for the iphone I could use the adobe AIR

I have no idea what or where to go to start,
if it's really possible to do so with Flash CS5 then I'd get it,
But I'd be glad if you guys could give me some direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes now you can use Flash CS5 and AIR Sdk to do the development.. Its 100% legal.

Comment: Do I need to use Actionscript 3 for that? or do I have to learn a whole new language?

Comment: yes you can deploy app using html,action script,java script flash etc. and remember to tick my answer if it is helpful

Comment: Thank you very much, you did help me a lot here, I'm still a little confused though to be honest, I mean, you're saying that I can make an app using all of those languages you've mentioned, but as far as I know, flash only accepts actionscript, could you please explain it a bit more mate? thank you soo much in advance

Comment: @Don Sorry to have to say this, but using Google was not an option? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Comment: Hi, yes, trust me I've been googling this a lot, I wouldn't ask about it here if I weren't lost, while I was googling I found that Apple has blocked those things, and I got pretty much lost about what's still legal to use, and what isn't

Comment: The link I included is an official Adobe document, which was the first result in the list when googling "iOS development actionscript"...  Seems a bit obvious, doesn't it?